# textarea.value returns initial value, not edited value

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm trying to create a preview for my CMS with TinyMCE. When clicking the preview link
`<a href="javascript:preview()">preview</a>`, the function preview gets started properly:

```
function preview() {
    w = window.open("preview.php?text=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByName("content")[0].value), "Vorschau", "width=" + screen.width + ",height=" + screen.height);
    //...
}
```

the textarea is defined as `<textarea name="content" rows="30" cols="100">Some text form a database.</textarea>`. When I try to open the preview of an edited text, the text from the database is loaded.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: As it seems to be 100% related to tinyMCE, I've added the related tag.

Comment: I believe TinyMCE replaces (or hides) the actual `textarea` with another element. Use the TinyMCE API to get the value.

Comment: Thanks to Felix King. This was the solution.